# Use label or node to optimize query cypher

Tags: optimization, graph, neo4j

I need to know which users in my database are active and which are not. The first way is to put the typical Property **Active** and set it with true or false, but in a query to return the active users would have to go through all nodes. I think it can be optimized in several ways. The first would be to create a node that is **Active** so that active users have a relation `MATCH (u:User)-[:IS]-> (Active) return u`, the other would be, create a label **:Active** so that to return it would be `MATCH (u:Active) RETURN u`. Similar to the answer: [Neo4j node property type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20430966/9301998). Personally I think that assigning the label is more efficient, what I do not know is how can I return the users who are not active, I would not like to create a second label for Inactive. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give have each `User` a boolean `active` property, and create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/schema/index/) on it, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(active);
```

Then, you can quickly get all active users like this:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.active
RETURN u;
```

and all non-active users like this:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE NOT u.active
RETURN u;
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a more in-depth test, I added to the database **240'014** users of them **120'000** were marked as active, to do the 3 types of queries:

1. **with a property active**:
   `match(c:User) where c.active=true return c.name` delayed **285ms**
   `match(c:User) where c.active=true return count(c)` delayed **75ms**
2. **with a label :Active**:
   `match(c:Active) return c.name` delayed **271ms**
   `match(c:Active) return count(c)` delayed **1ms**
3. **with a node Active**:
   `match(c:User)-[:IS]->(:Active) return c.name` delayed **433ms**
   `match(c:User)-[:IS]->(:Active) return count(c)` delayed **167ms**

Comment: Since you also wanted to find all inactive users, you should also show the performance of that "harder" use case (which would also show you how difficult it would be to implement the use case). Also, are the above times an average of multiple trials or just the first trial (which would usually be slower, since the query plan would not yet be cached)?

Comment: Hello @cybersam. The times shown is an average of several queries, always the lowest response time was using the **: Active** label for the nodes that are active, even in the first query that was not in cache, but I do not know how to return the nodes that do not have the **: Active** lavel? and that's my initial question, I could put a **: Inactive** label, although I'm not sure it's a good practice. On the other hand I am using the **neo4j-php-ogm** library and I do not know if I can mark an object with several labels and how to manage these labels later?

Comment: The approach with the `active` property does take care of all your use cases AND with an index should be pretty fast. Did you test with an index?

Comment: yes @cybersam, the first case(**with a property active**) I used an index, and it's pretty similar to labels